# Problems publishing to iOS from FlashDevelop: compile-abc not compatible

Tags: ios, publish, flashdevelop

I've been trying to get FlashDevelop to export to iOS and after some struggling I thought I was almost there. Unfortunately I now get a message that "This version of C:...\compile-abc-64.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you are running".

I'm on a 32-bit machine so I'm guessing that the problem is I need to tell the packager to run the 32-bit version of the compiler. But I can't seem to find any way to do that, or anyone else who has encountered this problem. Anyone know where I should be looking?

I've tried all the obvious things, like looking for any reference to compile-abc in the various batch files. There's a file called compile-abc.exe in the same folder as compile-abc-64.exe, and I even tried simply renaming this file to compile-abc-64.exe but that brought up another error message so I'm guessing there's a bit more to it than that.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to additional compiler options:

*-useLegacyAOT yes*